# show and hide drop down list on Button click?

Tags: android, button

I am using a button and on clicking it ,a drop down list opens and the arrow sign changes.but I want to hide the drop down list on button's click again.mean to show and hide alternately on button's click. i am using this code.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myphotosBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.myPhotosBtn);
    myphotosBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        arrowDown.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_up);
       findViewById(R.id.dropdownList).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

please help.

Comment: you can show and hide image when one single button click event .right?

Comment: yes i want to do this. i am able to show list on button's click but wants to hide list on its click again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use boolean.

Lets say..

```
    boolean isButton=true;


     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myphotosBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.myPhotosBtn);
        myphotosBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


            if(isButton){
                        arrowDown.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_up);
                       findViewById(R.id.dropdownList).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                       isButton=false;
            }else{
                        arrowDown.setImageResource(R.drawable.down);
                       findViewById(R.id.dropdownList).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                       isButton=true;
                 }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Glad to help you Nidhi.

Comment: hi Hardy. Could u please tell why the list opens only on double-clicking of button? its not working on single click

Comment: @Nidhi Means at the first time click it is not visible ? After that per click its visible and gone.. this is issue ?

Comment: You need to set default  of isButton=true;

Comment: yeah it works.. thank you so much.. actually i am pretty new to android so don't know about these things deeply..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37729/discussion-between-hardy-and-nidhi)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myphotosBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.myPhotosBtn);
    Boolean temp=false;
    myphotosBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        if(temp){
           arrowDown.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_down);
           findViewById(R.id.dropdownList).setVisibility(View.GONE);
           temp=false;
        }else{

            arrowDown.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_up);
            findViewById(R.id.dropdownList).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            temp=true;
        }


        }
    });
```

Take this as a reference and develop your logic.

Another way to implement this is, Use CheckBox instead of Button, and write onChecked method code. You can achieve this using it also.

Comment: thanks 4 your reply. but this method had some faults. i have used Hardy's method. that one is perfectly right.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean isshow=false;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myphotosBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.myPhotosBtn);

    myphotosBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!isshow)
                arrowDown.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_up);
                findViewById(R.id.dropdownList).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                isshow=true;
            } else {
                arrowDown.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_up);
                findViewById(R.id.dropdownList).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                isshow=false;
            }
        });
```

You can use `sharedpreferences` to store booolean variable value.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is already answered, but if you might stumble upon this looking for a dropdown functionality to create a menu: I'd like to point you to [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#PopupMenu).

It's Android standard how to create a popup menu (which looks exactly like a dropdown list under a button).